How to print an html page with a specific size into a pdf file
I want to print into a pdf file a html page with a specific customized dimension:
here the css part:
@media print {
        @page {
            size: 210mm 105mm;
            margins: 10mm 10mm 10mm 10mm;
        }
    }

and here the js code:
function printLogbook() {
        const logbook = document.getElementById("table");
        logbook.focus();
        logbook.contentWindow.print();
    }


Your CSS is working 100% and thus no need for JS but you could use some event to select something other than the page. your code has no minimal body or focus so all you have is/are the page[s].
Since printing is a client function. Just use the CSS and concentrate on applying it to elements.
The Printing is unimportant, as under user not server control.

Users can alter much of the "Save as Printed PDF" layout outside of JS remit.



there is an issue in how you're trying to trigger the print command for an iframe (logbook.contentWindow.print()), which may not work as expected
Instead of logbook.contentWindow.print(), use window.print() to trigger the print dialog for the whole page
function printLogbook() {
    window.print(); // Triggers the print dialog
}

If you need to export to PDF with the custom page size, you can use the jsPDF library:
function printToPDF() {
    const doc = new jsPDF({
        unit: 'mm',
        format: [210, 105], // Custom size
    });
    const logbook = document.getElementById("table");
doc.html(logbook, {
    callback: function (doc) {
        doc.save('logbook.pdf');
    },
    x: 10,
    y: 10
});


Sorry, but rep is not obtained through begging. Also it's not SO community's role to do your school's job of assessing your progres, teachers are paid for that.

I'd avoid to use external library. So there is an API for forse the browser to execute "Save as PDF", avoiding the client to see as first option the predefined printer?
